# Android. Metal detector

Tags: android

I've just watched this video showing off an app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qM3Zps_0pE&feature=player_embedded

At 3:34. How in the WORLD does it detect metal? I wasn't able to find anything on the web about it. Can anyone explain it to me please? Maybe offer some code or something ...

Thanks.

**EDIT**

How in the world is this not a real question? It's a programming related question asking how do you use an Android device to detect metal. I just don't understand some of you guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, you could use a magnetic field sensor, which is what I think they use in that video.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html

If you have trouble getting it to work, post your code and we can help you out.

Comment: Oh wow. Haha. How in the world didn't i think of that ! I've been programming Android devices for quite some time now. I'm such an idiot. Thanks Ed :))

Comment: no problem!  at first I thought it was fake but all the other demos were very possible and convincing

Answer (score 1):

In the video it was apparent the device was measuring micro Tesla (uT) .. Lol I didnt know Android had a class called `GeomagneticField` that is so cool!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the GeomagneticField class, there is also the SensorManager and the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Granted, not every device will actually have a magnetometer.  It's not the most widely supported feature in the Android ecosystem.